# Bootstrap - responsive cards nested in a container-card

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

I have this markup

```
<div class="container-fluid p-4" style="margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: -30px;" id="divUtility" runat="server">
<div class="card bg-secondary">
<div class="card-header text-white ">
</div>
<div class="row card-body">
   <div id="divCantieri" runat="server" class="col-sm-4 bg-secondary">
   ...
   </div>
   <div id="divImporta" runat="server" class="col-sm-4 bg-secondary">
   ...
   </div>
   <div id="divBatch" runat="server" class="col-sm-4 bg-secondary">
   ...
   </div>
   <div id="divCausali" runat="server" class="col-sm-4 bg-secondary">
   ...
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm facing is that the nested cards inside the big one are not responsive, so when I use the site on desktop I see them on the same row one after each other, if I use the smartphone I see them still inline but shrinked. When on smartphone I want them to display as they are a single column. How can I achieve this? Thanks

[example drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP0q2.png)

[actual graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0TQH.png)

**EDIT:**
With this markup I'm almost where I want, last thing to figure out is how to set all the inner cards always adapting to the available horizontal space in both cases: basically when they are on a single row they should have width=33% each, but when on a single column width=100%.

```
<div id="divUtility" class="container-fluid p-4" style="margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: -30px;">
            <div class="card bg-secondary">
                <div class="card-header text-white ">
                ...
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap:wrap;">
                        <div id="divCantieri" class="card mr-3 mt-2 mb-2" style="min-width:30em;">
                            <div class="card-header bg-light">
                             ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body scroll" style="max-height: 10em;">
                            ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="divImporta" class="card mr-3 mt-2 mb-2" style="min-width:30em;">
                            <div class="card-header bg-light">
                             ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body scroll" style="max-height: 10em;">
                             ...
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="divBatch" class="card mr-3 mt-2 mb-2" style="min-width:30em;">
                            <div class="card-header bg-light">
                             ...
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body scroll" style="max-height: 10em;">
                             ...
                            </div>

                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap is based on 12 columns per row.  Your columns are adding up to 16.

Comment: @pcalkins that just means each div will take up 4 columns, it's okay to go above 12 if they wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this and it's working well, as wanted

```
<div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div id="divCantieri" runat="server" class="col-xl-4 mb-3">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header bg-light">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body scroll" style="max-height: 10em;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="divImporta" runat="server" class="col-xl-4 mb-3">
                        <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header bg-light">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body" style="max-height: 10em;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="divBatch" runat="server" class="col-xl-4 mb-3">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header bg-light">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body scroll" style="max-height: 10em;">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="divCausali" visible="false" runat="server" class="col-xl-4 mb-3">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header bg-light">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body scroll" style="max-height: 10em;">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use flexbox to achieve what you're after.

Set `display:flex;` on the div that contains the divs that you want to display as a column instead of a row. Then set their direction with `flex-direction:row;` and whether or not they'll wrap with `flex-wrap:wrap;`

```
<div class="row card-body" style="display:flex; flex-direction:row; flex-wrap:wrap;">
    <div id="divCantieri" runat="server" class="col-sm-4 bg-secondary">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="divImporta" runat="server" class="col-sm-4 bg-secondary">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="divBatch" runat="server" class="col-sm-4 bg-secondary">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="divCausali" runat="server" class="col-sm-4 bg-secondary">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a nice reference that helped me understand flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: nothing changes, the inner cards still squeeze on a smaller resolution

Comment: After some try I'm almost there, if I change the inner div class to "card mr-3 mt-2 mb-2" they are displayed in a row when on desktop and in column when on small screen. The only thing left is that they don't adapt to the horizontal space available

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by adapt, but there are 3 settings that come to mind: `space-around`, `space-between` and `space-evenly` that might get you what you're after. There's also `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow` that control how wide they'll get.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually telling the browser to set three columns for every view-port. You have to set the **col-sm** to 12 to make the divs occupy the entire row each.

```
<div class="row card-body">
   <div id="divCantieri" runat="server" class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 bg-secondary">
       ...
   </div>
   <div id="divImporta" runat="server" class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 bg-secondary">
       ...
   </div>
   <div id="divBatch" runat="server" class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 bg-secondary">
       ...
   </div>
   <div id="divCausali" runat="server" class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 bg-secondary">
       ...
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But if I set class=col-sm-12 then all the cards are displayed on different rows even on desktop version. I want them to be on a single column when on desktop and on different rows when on smaller screens

Comment: @GabrieleCozzolino, Have a look at your code I have changed some at this link. https://codepen.io/ahmadkarimi2009/pen/eYOrBqW, I think it works fine.

Comment: I don't know why but using your solution break the graphic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYWKE.png

Comment: Can you upload your code in codepen or somewhere so that I can have a look?